# Android Video api for multiple video layouts and editing

Tags: android, api, video, video-processing

I am currently working on a project which a user can select a "layout" (like 3 or 4 different videos in each corner, similar to acapella by picplaypost.), put videos to each corner, edit them individually,merge it with another video, merge the sounds,  play them together to see how videos are looking and make a single video out of it. I have found some API's, but they were either with paid license or lacked the requirements. Many of you may say FFmpeg but I think it lacks the "making single video out of it" part. A friend suggested me to use OpenGL to merge the videos but I lack the knowledge and experience to do anything with OpenGL. Any suggestions which is legal(like not reverse engineering the api's that I found)?

Sidenote: as an extra, if I can play a segment of a video in a number of loops, that would be awesome!

Comment: `I think [FFMpeg] lacks the "making single video out of it" part`: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate isn't what you are looking for?

Comment: Concatenation is from start to end but what I truly need is displaying four different videos at the same time, each video in one corner. Since I'm not a native speaker I can't describe what I want properly, but if you look at this image you will understand what I mean: [acappella](https://acapella-from-picplaypost.en.softonic.com/iphone)

Comment: I think you are looking for compositing. See: [ffmpeg - compositing a video within a video in the centre](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42519757/295004)